# How to iterate through Dictionary and change values?

Tags: .net, dictionary, c#-3.0

```
Dictionary<string,double> myDict = new Dictionary();
//...
foreach (KeyValuePair<string,double> kvp in myDict)
 {
     kvp.Value = Math.Round(kvp.Value, 3);
}
```

I get an error:
"Property or indexer 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair.Value' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only."
How can I iterate through `myDict` and change values?

Comment: If adding a lot of reference objects is acceptable from a performance perspective (indirection and more gc-pressure) _and_ you have control over the dictionary then creating a box for your values would solve the problem, e.g: `class Box<T> { public T boxed; }` and then use a `Dictionary<string, Box<double>>` which you can then "modify" in the foreach something like: `kvp.Value.boxed = 123.456;`. Not saying it is the "best" approach but it has its share of uses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Editing dictionary values in a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070766/editing-dictionary-values-in-a-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx):

> The foreach statement is a wrapper
>   around the enumerator, which allows
>   only reading from the collection, not
>   writing to it.

Use this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();
// TODO Populate your dictionary here
var keys = new List<string>(dictionary.Keys);
foreach (string key in keys)
{
   dictionary[key] = Math.Round(dictionary[key], 3);
}
```

Comment: I tested your example in .NET 2 and 3.5 and it throws 'Collection was modified exception'. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1562729/why-cant-we-change-values-of-a-dictionary-while-enumerating-its-keys  Has this changed in .NET 4 or did you not test your example?

Comment: How embarrassing - I left out the part where the list is populated. Fixed now. The idea here is that you can change the dictionary entry's value, just not its reference.

Comment: Wished you kept the question comment line with "//... (Populate)".  At quick glance the list is empty.

Comment: btw you can just do dictionary.Keys.ToList()

Comment: In .NET 5 you no longer need an extra list.

Answer (score 43):

For the lazy programmers:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();
foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys.ToList())
{
   dictionary[key] = Math.Round(dictionary[key], 3);
}
```

Comment: As I'm coding now with .NET 4.5, the `ToList()` method is unavailable, but the `Keys` member is iterable so `.ToList()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @MikeC see comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/2260462/1037948 -- you can't directly enumerate on the keys, the `.ToList()` is a "hack" to get around that

Comment: ToList() is a LINQ extension method. It should be available if you add "using System.Linq;" to your using statements.

Comment: @drzaus: Why can't you enumerate over Keys ? Keys is a dictionary, being enumerable just like any other dictionary. I am doing it without .ToList().

Comment: I know this is an old answer but I prefer it to the accepted one - I'd say rather than being lazy it's more concise (cuts out the line explicitly declaring the list of keys).  So, to answer the question above: you can enumerate over the keys collection, but the question is about enumerating and making changes, which you can't do.  Adding the ToList() means you're actually enumerating a list that happens to contain the same objects as the keys in the dictionary.  This leaves the dictionary itself mutable and so allows you to make changes.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't change the dictionary while iterating it, otherwise you get an exception.

So first copy the key-value pairs to a temp list and then iterate through this temp list and then change your dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, double> myDict = new Dictionary<string, double>();

// a few values to play with
myDict["a"] = 2.200001;
myDict["b"] = 77777.3333;
myDict["c"] = 2.3459999999;

// prepare the temp list
List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>(myDict);

// iterate through the list and then change the dictionary object
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> kvp in list)
{
    myDict[kvp.Key] = Math.Round(kvp.Value, 3);
}


// print the output
foreach (var pair in myDict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key + " = " + pair.Value);
}

// uncomment if needed
// Console.ReadLine();
```

output (on my machine):

> a = 2.2
>   b = 77777.333
>   c = 2.346

**Note**: in terms of performance, this solution is a bit better than currently posted solutions, since the value is already assigned with the key, and there's no need to fetch it again from the dictionary object.

Comment: That is probably the approach I will follow, but would love to know the overhead of copying the full dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

passed some time, but maybe someone is interested in it:

```
yourDict = yourDict.ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => Math.Round(kv.Value, 3))
```

Comment: Very readable version! Might become a little cluttered when adding error checks.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that fastest way (at this moment) iterate over Dictionary with modify is:

```
//Just a dumb class
class Test<T>
{
    public T value;

    public Test() { }
    public Test(T v) { value = v; }
}

Dictionary<int, Test<object>> dic = new Dictionary<int, Test<object>>();
//Init dictionary
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Test> pair in dic)
{
    pair.Value.value = TheObject;//Modify
}
```

VS

```
List<int> keys = new List<int>(dic.Keys); //This is fast operation   
foreach (int key in keys)
{
    dic[key] = TheObject;
}
```

First one takes about 2.2s and second one 4.5s (tested dictionary size of 1000 and repeated 10k time, changing dictionary size to 10 didn't change the ratios). Also there wasn't a big deal with getting the Key list, dictionary[key] value get is just slow VS built in iteration. Also if you want even more speed use hard coded type to dumb ("Test") class, with that I got it about 1.85s (with hard coded to "object").

**EDIT:**

Anna has posted the same solution before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6515474/766304

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to put the keys in a list (or another collection) beforehand and iterate through them while changing the dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, double> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, double>();

// Populate it
List<string> keys = new List<string>(dictionary.Keys);

foreach (string key in keys)
{
   dictionary[key] = Math.Round(dictionary[key], 3);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

While iterating over the dictionary directly is not possible because you get an exception (like Ron already said), you don't need to use a temp list to solve the problem.

Instead use not the `foreach`, but a `for` loop to iterate through the dictionary and change the values with indexed access:

```
Dictionary<string, double> myDict = new Dictionary<string,double>();
//...    
for(int i = 0; i < myDict.Count; i++) {
    myDict[myDict.ElementAt(i).Key] = Math.Round(myDict.ElementAt(i).Value, 3);
}
```

Comment: Although this will work, `Enumerable.ElementAt()` - which is the extension method you are using - is an [`O(n)` operation for non-`IList<>`s](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7db56d44563d8761,references).

Comment: Will say explicitly what Eugene Beresovsky is saying. This ends up being at least O(n^2). So this is a very bad solution.

Answer (score -3):

Loop through the keys in the dictionary, not the KeyValuePairs.

```
Dictionary<string, double> myDict = new Dictionary<string, double>();
//...
foreach (string key in myDict.Keys)
{
    myDict[key] = Math.Round(myDict[key], 3);
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly it throws a "*Collection modified...*" exception.

Comment: @Slauma Indeed *surprisingly*, as this change is not a structural change, therefore having the enumerator throw would in fact not be necessary.