# how to change the value of dictionary during looping

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, collections

How do I modify a value in Dictionary?  I want to reassign a value to a value in my dictionary while looping on my dictionary like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtParams.Count; i++)
{
   dtParams.Values.ElementAt(i).Replace("'", "''");
}
```

where `dtParams` is my `Dictionary`

I want to do some thing like this:

```
string a = "car";    
a = a.Replace("r","t");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to iterate through Dictionary and change values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260446/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-and-change-values)

Comment: they are similar but not the same,,, and the solution in How to iterate through Dictionary and change values? doesnot work with me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string Replace function returns a new modified string, so you'd have to do something like:

```
foreach (var key in dtParams.Keys.ToArray())
{
   dtParams[key] = dtParams[key].Replace("'", "''");
}
```

EDIT:

Addressed the collection is modified issue (which I didn't think would occur if you access a key that already exists...)

Comment: Exception::
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: try using a for loop or creating a new Dictionary and adding to it instead of removing. You cannot modify the members of the collection in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

when you use replace , it will return a new string instance , you need to assign the value in the dictionary after replace becaue string is immutable in nature

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this directly; you cannot modify a collection while you're enumerating it (also, avoid using `ElementAt` here; this is a LINQ to Objects extension method and is inefficient for iterating over an entire list). You'll have to make a copy of the keys and iterate over that:

```
foreach(var key in dtParams.Keys.ToList()) // Calling ToList duplicates the list
{
    dtParams[key] = dtParams[key].Replace("'", "''");
}
```

Comment: @user418343: If you want help, it would be easier if you'd say *how* it doesn't work (error message, bad output, etc.) rather than just saying "doesnot work also".

Comment: @user418343 It should work because that is one of the ways to look at each value in a dictionary collection and modify in the way your looking to do it. You won't be able to use a for loop for this particular task, you could keep track of the values you wanted to change, then modify only those after a single pass through.

Answer (score 1):

A little lambda will go a long way. ;)

I dropped this into LINQPad and tested it out for you.  All the collections have .To[xxx] methods so you can do this quite easily in 1 line.

```
var dtParams = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dtParams.Add("1", "'");
dtParams.Add("a", "a");
dtParams.Add("b", "b");
dtParams.Add("2", "'");
dtParams.Add("c", "c");
dtParams.Add("d", "d");
dtParams.Add("e", "e");
dtParams.Add("3", "'");

var stuff = dtParams.ToDictionary(o => o.Key, o => o.Value.Replace("'", "''"));
stuff.Dump();
```