# Setting dictionary value from withn foreach loop

Tags: c#

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but can't find anything that matches everything I need. I have an object, one of the members of which is a `Dictionary` object, defined as follows:

```
public class MyTestObject
{
    public int index { get; set; }
    // various other members here
    public Dictionary<string, bool> MyTestValues { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of class `MyTestObject`:

```
List<MyTestObject> values = new List<MyTestObject>();
```

I have a loop that runs through each instace of values and a sub-loop which runs through the KVP in the dictionary

```
foreach (MyTestObject current in values)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> testCurrent in current.MyTestValues)
    {
    }
}
```

Within the 2nd loop I need to change boolean value of each of the Dictionary items and this is where I am falling down.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something similar to the following:

```
values[current.index].MyTestValues.Where(t => t.Key == testCurrent.Key).Single().Value = true;
```

i.e., it's using the index member to access the field in the object and update the value.  Unfortunately this doesn't work as it says the Value field is read only.

I'm sure I'm getting confused unnecessarily here.  Any advice appreciated

Comment: It seems like you could just use `values[current.index].MyTestValues[testCurrent.Key] = true` unless I'm misunderstanding something?

Comment: `I am falling down`. What's the problem?

Comment: @hamlet - the Value field is read only.

Comment: @Andrew Don't try and modify the `KeyValuePair`s directly. Access the items in the dictionary through the indexer.

Comment: You're trying to modify the contents of the dictionary in a foreach which isn't valid? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260446/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-and-change-values

Comment: @Damon.  I'm not - in my code you can see I am trying to modify the values object, which is defined outside the foreach loop.  I realise you can't modify objects you get from within the for loop which I is why I am doing it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
values[current.index].MyTestValues[testCurrent.Key] = true;
```

It will update the existing value and if the `key` doesn't exist, it will add the new item in the dictionary with the new key.

Comment: @Magus, in that case it is better to check for Key using `ContainsKey`

Comment: My comment was dumb. You are correct. `ContainsKey` is the best way to do a check.

Comment: Hmmmm...I get an index out of range, which doesn't make much sense.  I will check further, but I think this is the way to go.

Comment: Ignore.  Me being an idiot and setting the value of index to 1 instead of 0 :)