# Update Dictionary Value field through loop

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have defined a `Dictionary`  as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, double> collection = new Dictionary<string, double>();
```

Now i want to update my Value:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> pair int collection)
{
    double val = 3.0;
    collection[pair.Value] = val; // Get an error
}
```

My error is Cannot convert from double to string.
Why is that ?

Comment: that won't compile `int` should be `in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate over a `Dictionary` and change the internal value as it will break the iterator.

you need to copy the collection, and modify the copied version...example below:

```
Dictionary<string, double> collection = new Dictionary<string, double>();
collection.Add("A", 1.0);
collection.Add("B", 2.0);

Dictionary<string, double> collection2 = new Dictionary<string, double>(collection);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> pair in collection)
{
  double val = 3.0;              
  collection2.Remove(pair.Key);
  collection2.Add(pair.Key, val);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   Dictionary<string, double> Copycollection= new Dictionary<string, double>  (collections);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> pair in Copycollection)
             {
                double val = 3.0;
                collection[pair.Key] = val; 
            }
```

Comment: This won't work as you are not allowed to change collection during enumerating. See [related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2260446/1997232) question.