# F# System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: list, dictionary, f#

i am encountering this problem in F#
[not C# where there is already a similar post with a similar answer]

I understand its not possible to modify a Dictionary while enumerating it in a for loop
how should i go around that ?

```
let edgelist1 = [(1,2,3.0f);(1,2,4.0f);(5,6,7.0f);(5,6,8.0f)]
let dict_edges = new Dictionary<int*int,(int*int*float32) list>()
for x in edgelist1 do dict_edges.Add ((fun (a,b,c)-> (a,b)) x, x)
for k in dict_edges.Keys do dict_edges.[k] <- (dict_edges.[k] |> List.rev)
```

> System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration
>   operation may not execute.
>
> > at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
> >     resource)    at
> >     System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.KeyCollection.Enumerator.MoveNext()
> >     at .$FSI_0101.main@()

individually this is working

```
dict_edges.[(1,2)] <- dict_edges.[(1,2)] |> List.rev;;
```

in the for loop i need just to change dictionary values, not keys.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to iterate through Dictionary and change values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260446/how-to-iterate-through-dictionary-and-change-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted is not even syntactically correct, so it's not clear what precisely you are trying to achieve (compiler screams at `((fun (a,b,c)-> (a,b)) x, x)` saying that it expects the second `x` to be a list)

I guess what you are after is: You have a list of weighted edges, where there can be multiple edges between nodes. You'd like to collapse them into a canonical form, where you have all edges grouped that connect any pair of nodes `(i,j)`. Just use any of the `groupBy` library functions, and you're good:

```
let map_edges =
    edgelist1
    |> List.groupBy (fun (a, b, _) -> (a, b))
    |> Map.ofList
```

In the current code you are using `((fun (a,b,c)-> (a,b)) x, x)` to extract members of a tuple. Instead, use patterns right in the `for` expression:

```
for (a, b, c) in edgelist1 do dict_edges.Add ((a, b), [(a, b, c)])
```

(I've added `[]` to make it at least compile)

Note also that you are duplicating information: You store the node tuple in the keys and in the values of the list, making the data structure possibly inconsistent and larger. Consider the following:

```
let map_edges =
    edgelist1
    |> List.map (fun (a, b, c) -> (a, b), c)
    |> List.groupBy fst
    |> List.map (fun (nodeTuple, edgeList) -> 
        nodeTuple, (edgeList |> List.map snd))
    |> Map.ofList


map_edges
|> Map.iter (fun (nodeI, nodeJ) edgeList ->
    edgeList
    |> Seq.map string
    |> String.concat "; "
    |> printfn "Nodes (%i, %i): weights %s" nodeI nodeJ
)
```

(You may want to use sequences as the intermediate representation rather than list)

Comment: thanks i didn't know about List.groupby, i rewrote this function myself !

Answer (score 5):

You can copy all the keys into a temporary list, and then iterate over that list while modifying the original dictionary:

```
for k in (dict_edges.Keys |> Seq.toList) do 
   dict_edges.[k] <- (dict_edges.[k] |> List.rev)
```

But I would strongly advise you to rethink your approach and get rid of in-place mutation. This little problem you're facing right now is only the first taste of what could go wrong with a mutation-based program.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to just say dict_edges = dict_edges.map( $0.reverse())

Sorry about the bad f# syntax